# Angular2 http.get in constructor can't see 'this'

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to get data from server, and constructor of class can't see `this` of class to save incoming data to variable from `this`.

```
import  {Injectable} from '/angular2/core';
import {GameModel} from 'app/model/games/games';
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http} from 'angular2/http';
@Component({
    providers: [HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http]
})
export class DataProvider {
    games:GameModel[];

    constructor(private http:Http) {
        console.log('this.games constructor', this.games); //undefined
        http.get('app/service/php/games.php')
            //.map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(function (data) {
                var games = [];
                var response = data.json();

                for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                    var game = new GameModel(
                        response[i].id,
                        response[i].gameName,
                        response[i].fullName,
                        response[i].altname,
                        response[i].description,
                        response[i].minPlayers,
                        response[i].maxplayers,
                        '',
                        response[i].bgglink);
                    games.push(game);
                }
                this.games = games;
                console.log('this.games', this.games); //undefined
            });
    }
    getGames() {
        return Promise.resolve(this.games);
    }
}
```

In class `DataProvider` I declare `games:GameModel[]`. The constructor can't see `games:GameModel[]`. After receive data I want to return it in `getGames()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use arrow functions for your callbacks to be able to use lexical `this`:

```
.subscribe((data) => {
  this.games = [];
  var response = data.json();
  (...)
});
```

See this link for more hints about the lexical this of arrow functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions.

Comment: Is it true that 'var games = [];' is created locally? I need to get to variable from class.

Comment: You can use `this.games = [];` directly. `this` corresponds to the component instance. I updated my answer.